# What design pattern/s best to use when retrieving data series for chart

Tags: laravel, design-patterns

I have backend API that have group of methods that retrieves some data series for charts in web/mobile apps from database by different sql-queries.

Some data series uses as-is, another - calculated from reteved data series.

At this time I have Controller that call Repository. And if I need to calculate data then I pass data to math function and get another series.

And I am stuck in how to clearly organize my code. What design-patterns to use? How to separate code?

pls, help :)

Comment: Are you using framework? If yes which framework are you using? So that we can be able to help

Comment: Yes, Laravel(php)